# SwiperJS (React) - How to make 3 dot pagination

Tags: html, css, reactjs, swiper.js

By default, when using the dynamicBullets parameter, the pagination display uses 5 points (one active, two previous, two next) - a total of 5. I'm trying to make the number of points 3 (one active, previous and next). To do this I am trying to change the classes property:

```css
 :global(.swiper-pagination-bullet-active-prev-prev) {
     visibility: hidden;
 }

 :global(.swiper-pagination-bullet-active-next-next) {
     visibility: hidden;
 }
```

But in the end I get this effect (attached gif). You can see how the boundary point disappears when it reaches the container. How can I fix this? Maybe someone has a better solution than changing style properties. It is advisable to leave the default behavior.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

instead of hiding the elements with visibility: hidden, you can try adjusting their opacity to make them less visible while still maintaining their space in the layout. For example:

```
:global(.swiper-pagination-bullet-active-prev-prev),
:global(.swiper-pagination-bullet-active-next-next) {
    opacity: 0.5; /* Adjust the opacity value as needed */
}
```

Comment: I also tried this solution, but it doesn't work for me. I just need to remove them.

Comment: Try to use display: none;

Comment: display: none; completely breaks pagination in Swiper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
:global(.swiper-pagination-bullet:not(:nth-child(2)):not(:nth-child(3)):not(:nth-child(4))) {
    visibility: hidden;
}

:global(.swiper-pagination-bullet:nth-child(2),
        .swiper-pagination-bullet:nth-child(3),
        .swiper-pagination-bullet:nth-child(4)) {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. We can't hide anything because every next bullet is used and becomes an active class. If we try to hide the bullet, it will not become active when it gets its turn.

Comment: Swiper creates a number of points in the DOM tree equal to the number of slides and then changes them by assigning the classes ...-active-prev-prev, ...-active-prev, ...-active, ...-active-next, . ..-active-next-next. And besides, all points have the default class ...-bullet